# No gvfs mounts in /run/user/

Tags: mount, samba, gvfs

I want to access a Samba share via the normal file system (using a bash script). Afaik the way should be:

1. Install `gvfs-fuse`
2. Make user part of `fuse` group
3. Reboot

I can access the samba share via Nautilus and `gvfs-mount -l` shows the mount:

```
$ gvfs-mount -l
Mount(0): hddrive2go auf speedport -> smb://speedport/hddrive2go/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

Unfortunately, my `/run/user/1001/gvfs` directory (and also `~/.gvfs`) is empty.

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

The log `journalctl --system | grep gvfs` does not show anything interesting.

The `gvfsd-fuse` daemon is running:

```
$ ps ax | grep gvfsd
 5918 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 5923 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs -f -o big_writes
 6025 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 7015 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
 7031 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
 7048 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
25891 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-network --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
25938 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-dnssd --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/6
27616 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/7
27626 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/8
28312 pts/18   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gvfsd
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1451087

Not sure if there's a better workaround than the suggestions in that link:

> Anyway my work round for this issue is to unmount my smb drive, kill off gvfs and restart

or

> Killing gvfsd and quitting nautilus afterwards (nautilus -q) put things right temporarily.